# Cannot delete lightning component

Tags: lightning, community, delete

Need help. I am deleting a few obsolete/test lightning components (*.cmp) from our sandbox. There's this one component that I cannot delete. When I tried to delete, Dev Console would give me a message that says:

> **DEPENDENCY_EXISTS**
>
> Cannot complete this operation. The object you're trying to delete is
> in use on site [community name], which is under development. : Site

I am very sure that it is no longer used in that community. I have deactivated the site. I have changed the template to VF tabs, and other templates but to no avail.

Still getting the same message when deleting that component.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please check the page variation in the community and see if that component is referenced there or not.

Comment: not there. it is now in VF + Tabs template. so no page variations.

Comment: @pnoytechie Was this ever solved?  I have the same problem.