# Can't delete lightning web component previously used in enhanced experience site

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page

I am trying to delete a lightning web component via the Salesforce CLI with `sfdx force:source:delete`.
I have removed the component from any experience page layout, but I still get the following error:

> The object you're trying to delete is in use on site [site_name], which is under development. : Managed Content Resource - [site_name]--sfdc_cms__site. The object you're trying to delete is in use on site [site_name], which is published. : Managed Content Resource -[site_name1]--sfdc_cms__site.

Enhanced Salesforce CMS is enabled and connected to the concerning site.

Comment: Do you see any references in that experience site's>Workspaces> Administration> Pages> Site.com Studio> Page templates?

Comment: I don't see access to Site.com Studio. Do I need a license for that?

Comment: Have you actually published the experience site since removing the component from the page?

Comment: I did. 
Before, I got a different error message when the component was added to an experience builder page and I tried to delete it.

Comment: No license needed. Related [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.siteforce_page_edit.htm&type=5)

Comment: I can't see a Site.com studio option. See my comments on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/257700/78690.

Comment: What is the experience site's template?

Comment: It's a LWR template.